# Periodic timer not working with .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem:**

I believe that .load is blocking but is intended to be asynchronous.

**Code:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#content').load('/ajax/databaseworking.php');
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#content').load('/ajax/databaseperform.php');}, 5000);
});
</script>
```

**Further Details:**

The code basically calls databaseworking.php to do some database maintenance. Every 5 seconds, an ajax call is made to get its progress.

I have checked my logs. databaseworking.php and databaseperform.php are being called. However, databaseperform.php is not being called periodically. In other words, its only being called once.

As a test, I commented out the databaseworking call. This lead to the the progress function being called per interval as intended. This makes me believe that there is a problem with load. Note I have checked and tested databaseworking.php and there shouldnt be an error in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTimeout` will only run once. I believe you wanted to use `setInterval` which is a recurring timer

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: Because of the difference between `setTimeout` and `setInterval` it is very likely that in this situation the OP would prefer using repeat `setTimeout` or `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a new timeout in your function.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var loadContent = function() {
      $('#content').load('/ajax/databaseperform.php');
      setTimeout(loadContent, 5000);
    };
    loadContent();
});
```

You can see why this is likely preferable to using `setInterval` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/330013